# code gives error Segmentation fault (core dumped), if location is changed

Tags: c, fonts

I am trying to customize the header of a type1 font file by changing some text from 6th byte to 20th byte as mentioned in code below.

Currently font file contains this text in 6-20 bytes "%!PS-AdobeFont", i am modifying it to "%!PS-RoughFont". Its working fine, but as soon as i install this font file in fonts folder where all fonts are installed and run the same code it gives me error  "**Segmentation fault (core dumped)**"

why is this error coming i mean same code working in other location. P.S i am using linux OS. Is it something to the permissions of this directory as it allows only read permission.

Code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
 FILE *fp;

 fp = fopen("/usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/test.pfb","r+");

 fseek(fp, 6, 0);
 fputs("%!PS-AdobeFont", fp);
 fclose(fp);

 return(0);
}
```

Comment: Clearly if the directory *allows only read permission*, you can't open a file to **write** to it. *Read permission* means you can *read*, not *write*. So the `fopen()` call failed, and the file was not opened for writing, yet you just go ahead and write to it anyway, writing to an invalid file pointer. You should learn to a) check function results instead of just assuming they worked, and b) learn now to use a debugger.

Comment: @KenWhite actually the file has permission that root user can write i tried it with sudo command while compiling still it failed.

Comment: @KenWhite thanks your comment helped sudo did the trick for me..

Comment: Clearly something is wrong with your call to `fopen()`, because all the other code is based on it succeeding. Basic error checking and stepping through the code with the debugger would tell you exactly where the problem is located, at which point you can try to figure out how to fix it. We're not your surrogate debuggers. :-) **Stop** just assuming that function calls worked, and use proper checking of the return values.

Comment: @KenWhite thank you ill be careful next time about debugging.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have write permissions.

Use this code that includes error checking to see what the problem is:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE* fp = fopen("/usr/share/fonts/type1//gsfonts/test.pfb", "r+");
    if(!fp)
    {
        perror("Error");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    fseek(fp, 6, 0);
    fputs("%!PS-AdobeFont", fp);
    fclose(fp);
}
```